# HMS ASR cannot start recording

Tags: android, multithreading, voice-recognition, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

I'm trying to add HMS automatic speech recognition (ASR) to my app. I already have `SpeechRecognizer` implemented, but it requires GMS to work.

The current HMS implementation works on a non-huawei device with HMS core installed, but does not work on my Huawei Mediapad T5.

#### Things I've tried

The methods are called from different threads (main thread and graphics thread), so I've tried synchronizing the methods on a lock or `post`ing a `Runnable` to the activity handler, without making much a difference. I.E., wrapping the functions in `synchronized(lock)` or `activity.post`.

#### Code:

- `fun init(activity: Activity)`

```
speechRecognizer = MLAsrRecognizer.createAsrRecognizer(activity)
speechIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    .putExtra(
        MLAsrCaptureConstants.LANGUAGE,
        "en-US"
    )
    .putExtra(MLAsrConstants.FEATURE, MLAsrConstants.FEATURE_ALLINONE)
speechRecognizer?.setAsrListener(listener)
```

- `fun startListening()`

```
speechRecognizer?.startRecognizing(speechIntent)
```

- `fun destroy()`

```
speechRecognizer?.destroy()
```

#### Logs

```
4945-4945 W/HmsSpeechRecognitionHolder@c1cafe: init on Thread[main,5,main]
4945-4945 W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
4945-4945 W/HmsSpeechRecognitionHolder@c1cafe: startListening on Thread[main,5,main]
4945-4945 E/HaLogProvider: forbiddenHiLog openHa = false
4945-4945 E/HaLogProvider: forbiddenHiLog.getVenderCountry=ca
4945-4945 E/HaLogProvider: forbiddenHiLog openHa = false
4945-4945 E/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: mEventsToBeReported: has no response event isInfoGatherStart:falsemsg: 0
4945-4945 E/HwCustAudioRecordImpl: isOpenEC : false
634-985 E/HuaweiProcessing: ProcessingLib_Create: the algo have already been created.
634-985 W/EffectsFactory: EffectCreate() library huawei_processing: could not create fx Huawei Audio Preprocessing Effect, error -22
634-985 E/EffectFactoryHAL: Error creating effect e707d040-6b79-11e2-b16a-0002a5d5c51b: Invalid argument
721-8060 E/AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -19
721-8060 W/AudioPolicyEffects: addInputEffects(): failed to create Fx huawei_pre_processing on source 1
634-8049 E/baidu_asr_interface: asr_baidu_set_parameters_data-not baidu asr
634-7993 W/DeviceHAL: Device 0x78c2d00000 get_mic_mute: Function not implemented
634-987 W/DeviceHAL: Device 0x78c2dc4680 get_mic_mute: Function not implemented
721-8009 W/HuaweiAudioFlinger: soundtrigger is now disable or not support, pls enable it first from setting
721-8009 W/APM_AudioPolicyManager: startInput(78) failed: other input 70 already started
721-8009 E/AudioFlinger: RecordThread::start error,setCallingAppName -1
4945-4945 E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
4945-4945 E/MLASR_A: getVendorCountry=ca
500-8480 W/libc: Set property "hw.wifi.dns_stat" to "99,14,14044,1,34759"
1472-1472 W/HwKeyguardDragHelper: AnimationBlocked
4945-5079 W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x79e0317010 disconnect failed
1140-2290 E/WindowManager: win=Window{d80c651 u0 ProjectActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
1140-1316 E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
767-767 E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
1140-1316 E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
761-8466 W/ACodec: forcing OMX state to Idle when received shutdown in ExecutingState
769-8467 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: onChangeState mState= 3, mTargetState = 3, state = 2
769-8467 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: checkTransitions port buf count is not zero
769-1826 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: checkTransitions port buf count is not zero
769-1826 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: checkTransitions port buf count is not zero
769-1826 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: checkTransitions port buf count is not zero
769-1826 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: checkTransitions port buf count is not zero
769-1826 W/SimpleSoftOMXComponent: checkTransitions mState = 2, mTargetState = 1
721-8060 W/HuaweiAudioFlinger: soundtrigger is now disable or not support, pls enable it first from setting
1900-3437 E/HSM: BMNCaller:is not PermissionEnabled.
721-6695 W/AudioFlinger::EffectModule: EffectModule 0x7ba4f22a00 destructor called with unreleased interface
634-941 E/audio_hw_primary: in_remove_audio_effect error effect is null
634-941 W/StreamHAL: Error from HAL stream in function remove_audio_effect: Function not implemented
721-6695 E/AudioFlinger::EffectModule: Error when removing effect: -38
721-6695 W/AudioFlinger::EffectHandle: disconnect Effect handle 0x7ba4e45800 disconnected after thread destruction
1640-1796 W/AudioState: session release  and not found  sessionId: 81
4945-4945 W/HmsSpeechRecognitionHolder@c1cafe: destroy on Thread[main,5,main]
4945-8481 E/HwCustAudioRecordImpl: isOpenEC : false
4945-8481 E/HwCustAudioRecordImpl: isOpenEC : false
```

#### Things I found suspicious in the logs

```
634-985 E/HuaweiProcessing: ProcessingLib_Create: the algo have already been created.
634-985 W/EffectsFactory: EffectCreate() library huawei_processing: could not create fx Huawei Audio Preprocessing Effect, error -22
634-985 E/EffectFactoryHAL: Error creating effect e707d040-6b79-11e2-b16a-0002a5d5c51b: Invalid argument
721-8060 E/AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -19
721-8060 W/AudioPolicyEffects: addInputEffects(): failed to create Fx huawei_pre_processing on source 1
721-8009 W/APM_AudioPolicyManager: startInput(78) failed: other input 70 already started
721-8009 E/AudioFlinger: RecordThread::start error,setCallingAppName -1
4945-4945 E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
```

**Note:** the HMS demo apps I've tried works correctly on my Mediapad T5.

**Update:** After some fixes pointed out by @shirley, ASR seems to be working reliably on a P30Lite. But still facing the same issue on an older Mediapad T5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs you provided, the voice of the user is not detected.
The meanings of logs and status codes are as follows:
[image]

[image]

**solution**

1. It is recommended that you add logs to the callback method of the MLAsrListener listener to view the speech recognition process.

[image]

2. You are advised to check `mSpeechRecognizer.destroy()`. Check whether this method is invoked prematurely and has ended before it starts.
3. Check whether the device is faulty or whether the microphone of the device is invalid. Replace the device and perform the test.

---

After reviewing your logs, the following errors were found:
[image]

The reason for this error is:The Languagecode for speech recognition exceeds 10.

You can view the code here:
[image]

Ensure that the speech recognition Languagecode does not exceed 10.

---

> `11203 ,subError code: 3002,errorMessage: Service unavailable`

The cause of this error is that the `app_id` information is not found in the project.

You are advised to check whether the agconnect-services.json file exists in the project, as shown in the following

[image]

[image]

If the file does not exist, you need to add it to the project. If the file exists, ensure that `app_id` is correct.

For details, see the following [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/add-appgallery-0000001050038080?ha_source=hms1).

---

1. Check whether Automatic Speech Recognition fails to be enabled.

   If Automatic Speech Recognition fails to be enabled, you can obtain the cause by using the `onError(int error, String errorMessage)` method of the MLAsrListener class, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

You can add the above method to the listener's class:
[image]

2.If speech recognition is enabled successfully but the speech recognition result is not obtained:

The `MLAsrConstants.FEATURE` parameter is set to `FUNCTION_ALLINONE`. Therefore, you need to obtain the speech recognition result in the `onResults(Bundle results)` method, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I get the error code `11203 ,subError code: 3002,errorMessage: Service unavailable`

Comment: hi@Daniel , i updated my answer,pls kindly refer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `agconnect-services.json` is set up correctly. The same configuration works with https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ml-demo when the package name is set correctly. Also my current code works when running on a non-huawei phone with HMS core installed.

Comment: hi@Daniel,Could you provide a full log, so we can help you properly?

Comment: Do you want logs down to debug level of the ones already provided or do you want logs starting earlier and ending later in time?

Comment: hi@Daniel,the following is log extraction Method,pls refer:
Connect the ADB to the phone and run the following commands:
adb logcat-v time > D:\hwml.log
2. Reproduce the problem scenario.
3. Press Ctrl+C to finish.

Comment: Here: https://upload.disroot.org/r/84KrdoMZ#RkxoGiAJaPDW34vdgIXowv/4WbXeaXaGZDXVfq1kMDs= 
It's too big for stackoverflow

Comment: hi@Daniel , just updated my answer,pls kindly refer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230593/discussion-between-daniel-and-shirley).

Comment: I've accepted your solution, since it helped me to get it working on a P30Lite. It's still not working on my Mediapad T5. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in a demo app. There are simply too many things happening in my app.

Comment: ok,and please feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some models of phones and tablets could have resource limitation issues when using the ML ASR. The symptom of the problem is that the phone/tablet does not respond after the microphone button is clicked, or an error message is displayed indicating that the speech recognition service is not installed on the device. Not only HMS ASR, I tried using native Android SpeechRecognizer to implement speech recognition and the sample app hangs after click on the button on a limited hardware resource phone simulator.

To fix your issue, I would suggest to switch using the HMS ML Kit ASR to using HMS ML Kit Real-Time Transcription (RTT). RTT provides similar features as ASR for speech recognition and convert the speech to text. For more details, see the HMS ML Kit RTT document at [ML Kit-Real-Time Transcription](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/real-time-transcription-0000001054964200-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001054964200__section1538393817134) (huawei.com).

The code for RTT is similar to ASR, you need to provide a SpeechRecognitionListener class or anonymous class to implements MLSpeechRealTimeTranscriptionListener. And there is sample code at the document link too. I tested the sample code on my Huawei phone Mate 30 Pro and it is working just fine.

Comment: It's not the device. The huawei demo apps github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ml-demo works fine on the same device with ASR working as expected.

Comment: Real-Time Transcription also fails with similar log messages.